# How to generically create an Expression for a property?

Tags: c#, lambda

ExpressMapper has an `Ignore` method that looks like this:

```
public IMemberConfiguration<T, TN> Ignore<TMember>(Expression<Func<TN, TMember>> dest)
{
    if (dest == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("dst");
    }

    if (!(dest.Body is MemberExpression))
    {
        throw new Exception("MemberExpression should return one of the properties of destination class");
    }
    foreach (var typeMapper in _typeMappers)
    {
        typeMapper.Ignore(dest);
    }
    return this;
}
```

I would like to add my own `IgnoreAll` method that iterates over all properties on a Type and calls the `Ignore` method for each property. This is what I have so far:

```
public static IMemberConfiguration<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAll<TSource, TDestination>(
    this IMemberConfiguration<TSource, TDestination> config)
{
    var props = typeof (TDestination).GetProperties();

    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(TDestination).GetProperty(prop.Name);

        var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDestination), "e");
        Expression columnExpr = Expression.Property(entityParam, prop);

        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType != typeof(object))
            columnExpr = Expression.Convert(columnExpr, typeof(object));

        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TDestination, object>>(columnExpr, entityParam);

        config.Ignore(expression);
    }

    return config;
}
```

When this code is run, I get an error:

> MemberExpression should return one of the properties of destination
>   class

As you can see from the source of the `Ignore` method above, my generated expression is failing the following conditional:

```
if (!(dest.Body is MemberExpression))
{
    throw new Exception("MemberExpression should return one of the properties of destination class");
}
```

So my question is:

**What do I need to change in my extension method to make the correct `Expression` that the `Ignore` method is expecting?**

Edit: by the way, the full source for the `MemberConfiguration` class is here: https://github.com/fluentsprings/ExpressMapper/blob/master/ExpressMapper%20NET40/MemberConfiguration.cs

Comment: The problem is that you add `Convert`. It's a lot trickier than what you've got, because you need to call generic method from the context where one of the parameters is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured this out, and I gotta tell ya, it was a doozy.

```
public static IMemberConfiguration<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAll<TSource, TDestination>(
    this IMemberConfiguration<TSource, TDestination> config)
{
    // First we'll get the collection of properties to iterate over.
    var props = typeof (TDestination).GetProperties();

    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        // Get the property information.
        var propertyInfo = typeof(TDestination).GetProperty(prop.Name);

        // Create an expression that points to the property.
        var entityParameter = new ParameterExpression[]
        {
            Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDestination), "e")
        };
        var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(entityParameter[0], prop);

        // Create a Func<,> using the TDestination and the property's type
        // for the Type parameters.
        var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TDestination), propertyInfo.PropertyType);

        // We need to create an Expression using Expression.Lambda<>, but we
        // don't know the types involved so we have to do this using reflection.
        var lambdaMethod = typeof (Expression)
                .GetMethods()
                .Single(m => m.IsGenericMethod &&
                             m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(Expression) &&
                             m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(ParameterExpression[]));
        var lambdaMethodConstructed = lambdaMethod.MakeGenericMethod(funcType);
        var expression = lambdaMethodConstructed.Invoke(
                null,
                new object[] { propertyExpression, entityParameter });

        // Now we need to construct the Ignore method using the property's Type.
        var ignoreMethod = config.GetType().GetMethod("Ignore");
        var constructed = ignoreMethod.MakeGenericMethod(propertyInfo.PropertyType);

        // Finally, we call the constructed Ignore method, using
        // our expression as the argument.
        constructed.Invoke(config, new object[] { expression });
    }

    return config;
}
```